# Kafka+Java+SparkStreaming+reduceByKeyAndWindow throw Exception:org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: java, serialization, spark-streaming

I'm new for kafka and spark, and i'm trying to do some count, but not sucessful! The details of the problem are as follows. Thanks!

code as belows:

```
JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> counts = wordCounts.reduceByKeyAndWindow(new AddIntegers(), new SubtractIntegers(), Durations.seconds(8000), Durations.seconds(4000));
```

Exception as belows:

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task
>   not serializable  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions.reduceByKeyAndWindow(PairDStreamFunctions.scala:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions.reduceByKeyAndWindow(PairDStreamFunctions.scala:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream.reduceByKeyAndWindow(JavaPairDStream.scala:352)
>     at KafkaAndDstreamWithIncrement.KDDConsumer.run(KDDConsumer.java:110)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   KafkaAndDstreamWithIncrement.KDDConsumer

Comment: Show us `addIntegers` and `subtractIntegers`

Comment: thanks for you advice! Before, i always foucus on "how to override reduceBykeyAndWindow". But now i find maybe it's wrong in addIntgers and subractIntegers. i tried, and  sucessful,Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code as belows(define static):

```
static Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer> AddIntegers = new Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>(){
    @Override
    public Integer call (Integer i1,Integer i2){
       return i1 + i2;
    }
};
static Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer> SubtractIntegers = new Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>(){
    @Override
    public Integer call (Integer i1,Integer i2){
       return i1 - i2;
    }
};
```